# color by category using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, deep-learning, scikit-image

This is my code to create an annotated image with coco json and image.

```
I = io.imread('%s/images/%s'%(dataDir,img['file_name']))

axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_frame_on(False)
axes.set_xticks([]); axes.set_yticks([])

annpath = os.path.join(dataDir, 'AnnImages/')
if not os.path.exists(annpath):
 os.makedirs(annpath)
path=annpath+str(img['file_name'])[:-4]+'.jpg'

annotation_ids = coco.getAnnIds(imgIds=img['id'], catIds=catIds, iscrowd=None)
annotations = coco.loadAnns(annotation_ids)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9), dpi=155.9)
plt.imshow(I, interpolation='nearest')
plt.axis('off')

coco.showAnns(annotations)
    
plt.savefig(path, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

But it is output in different colors for each object..

I want to color each category.

Can you help me?

My annotate category : test , test2

[image]

Comment: Provide vmin/vmax in [imshow](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html), so that all images are scaled over the same range.

Comment: @Mr.T Thank you for your reply. I tried it, but it didn't get the image I wanted. I don't think I understand vmin and vmax. I added a photo above and modified it. It comes out in such a different color. If you don't mind, can you show me an example?

Comment: It's not clear what `coco` is. You should include how the `coco` object is created. Note that the [tag:coco] tag is unrelated ([something about coffescript](https://github.com/satyr/coco#readme)).